# Image doesn't show up in Jlabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I want to show an image in the label in the right after selecting a city in the combo box, but the image doesn't show up although there are no errors in the code syntax, and it doesn't show an error in the path of the image folder after the execution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class App  {

private JFrame frame;
JLabel picture;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                App window = new App();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
private Hashtable subItems = new Hashtable();

public App() {
    initialize();

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    String[] items = { "Select City", "Fes", "Sefrou", "Moulay Yaacoub" };
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items);
    comboBox.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    comboBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


    comboBox.setBounds(30, 32, 157, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);

    String[] subItems1 = { "Select Fes", "1", "2", "3" };
    subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);

    String[] subItems2 = { "Select Sefrou", "1", "2", "3" };
    subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);

    String[] subItems3 = { "Select Moulay Yaacoub", "1", "2", "3" };
    subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
    comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
    JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox(subItems1);

    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String item = (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            Object o = subItems.get( item );

            if (o == null)
            {
                comboBox_1.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel() );
            }
            else
            {
                comboBox_1.setModel( new DefaultComboBoxModel( (String[])o ) );
            }
        }
    });
    comboBox_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
            String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            updateLabel(petName);
        }
    });
    comboBox_1.setBounds(30, 63, 157, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox_1);

    JLabel Picture = new JLabel();
    updateLabel(subItems1[comboBox_1.getSelectedIndex()]);
    Picture.setBounds(236, 32, 188, 130);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Picture);

}

private void updateLabel(String name) {
    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/" + name + ".gif");
    picture.setIcon(icon);
    }


protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = test.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}


}
```

*code edited*
after the execution i get the 'java.lang.NullPointerException' because of this line  "picture.setIcon(icon);"
any idea how to fix the error ?

Comment: So where do you update the label with the Icon? I don't see where you use the `setIcon(...)` method of the label.  All I see is you creating a new Icon, but you don't do anything with it. By the way you are welcome for the help you received on your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56102199/add-new-combo-box-when-selecting-an-item-on-the-first-combo-box

Comment: code edited, sorry i forgot about the last oneit really helped.

Comment: You create two instances of your JLabel. One is an instance variable and one is a local variable. Get rid of the local variable.

Comment: thank you very much camickr for the help, problem solved, i deleted that and forgot to write the second one with p instead of capitale P .